# Class model for unknown json tree

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need a nittle hint how to design a class model for a specific json tree.
I had no influence on the json. Its generated by a webservice.

The json look like this:

```
{
   "version":"1",   
   "values":[
      {
         "2014-12-15 20:50:00":{            
            "energy":null,
            "temp":null
         }
      },
      {
         "2014-12-15 22:30:00":{            
            "energy":2328.42,
            "temp":null
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My first idea was that this is a Dictionary. Like this:

```
public class StecaRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("values")]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, InverterValue> Values
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [...]
```

But its not working. I think to be a Dictionary it has to look like this:

```
{
   "version":"1",   
   "values":[
      "2014-12-15 20:50:00":{            
         "energy":null,
         "temp":null
      },
      "2014-12-15 22:30:00":{            
         "energy":2328.42,
         "temp":null
      }
   ]
}
```

But what did I do now with the json in the first example?

Any idea?

thanks for your help
Steffen

Comment: The second version is not legal JSON. Arrays (`values`, in this case) can't take object-style keys (`"2014-12-15 20:50:00"`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be like this

```
public class ModelRoot
{
    public string Version { set; get; }
    public List<Dictionary<string,ModelValue>> values { set; get; }
    // This would work too
    //public List<Dictionary<DateTime,ModelValue>> values { set; get; }
}

public class ModelValue
{
    public string Energy { set; get; }
    public string Temp { set; get; }
}
```

---

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelRoot>(json);
```

Comment: Work perfect. Thank you! I'm feeling blind now x_x